# Toolbar in child window acting weird

Tags: winapi, toolbar, childwindow

Okay, so I'm using win32, with as few extra libraries as possible for the moment.  My application is divided into multiple child windows using splitterbars, and I've added a toolbar and status bar to the main window.  Now, I'm trying to add a toolbar to one of the child windows, and it works, but as soon as WM_SIZE happens, the buttons dissapear.  This is all done in the WndProc for the Main window, by the way.  Here's the code that creates the child window's toolbar:

```
toolRender = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, wndRender, NULL, gHinst, 0);

    SendMessage(toolRender, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
    SendMessage(toolRender, CCM_SETVERSION, (WPARAM)5, 0);

    himl = ImageList_LoadImage(NULL, L"buttons.bmp", 16, 2, RGB(0, 255, 255), IMAGE_BITMAP, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    SendMessage(toolRender, TB_SETIMAGELIST, 0, (LPARAM)himl);

    TBBUTTON tbb2[2];

    memset(tbb2, 0, sizeof(tbb2));
    tbb2[0].iBitmap = 0;
    tbb2[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb2[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb2[0].idCommand = TOOL_SAVEALL;
    tbb2[0].iString = (INT_PTR)L"Save All";

    tbb2[1].iBitmap = 1;
    tbb2[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb2[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb2[1].idCommand = TOOL_HELP;
    tbb2[1].iString = (INT_PTR)L"Help";

    SendMessage(toolRender, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(toolRender, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb2)/sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tbb2);
```

And here's my entire WM_SIZE message:

```
case WM_SIZE :
    {
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    // Resize toolbar
    SendMessage(toolMain, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(toolRender, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(statusMain, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);

    GetWindowRect(toolMain, &toolrect);
    GetWindowRect(statusMain, &statusrect);

    toolHeight = toolrect.bottom - toolrect.top;
    statusHeight = statusrect.bottom - statusrect.top;
    windowHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    GetWindowRect(toolRender, &toolrect);

    toolRendHeight = toolrect.bottom - toolrect.top;

    //Make sure window isn't too small
    if (rect.right < MINSIZE * 4)
    {
        rect.right = MINSIZE * 4;
        forceresize = true;
    }
    if (windowHeight < toolHeight + statusHeight + toolRendHeight + (MINSIZE * 2))
    {
        rect.bottom = toolHeight + statusHeight + toolRendHeight + (MINSIZE * 2);
        forceresize = true;
    }

    //resize splitters
    xDiv1 = rect.right * xDiv1p;
    xDiv2 = rect.right * xDiv2p;
    xDiv3 = rect.right * xDiv3p;
    yDiv = rect.bottom * yDivp;

    // Make sure splitters aren't beyond bounds
    if (xDiv3 > rect.right - MINSIZE)
        xDiv3 = rect.right - MINSIZE;
    else if(xDiv3 < xDiv2 + MINSIZE)
        xDiv3 = xDiv2 + MINSIZE;

    if (xDiv2 > xDiv3 - MINSIZE)
        xDiv2 = xDiv3 - MINSIZE;
    else if (xDiv3 < xDiv1 + MINSIZE)
        xDiv2 = xDiv1 + MINSIZE;

    if (xDiv1 > xDiv2 - MINSIZE)
        xDiv1 = xDiv2 - MINSIZE;
    else if (xDiv1 < MINSIZE)
        xDiv1 = MINSIZE;

    if (yDiv > rect.bottom - MINSIZE)
        yDiv = rect.bottom - MINSIZE;
    else if(yDiv < MINSIZE + toolrect.bottom)
        yDiv = MINSIZE + toolrect.bottom;

    // Resize windows
    MoveWindow(wndObjBrowser, 0, toolHeight, xDiv1 - SBS, windowHeight - toolHeight - statusHeight, FALSE);

    MoveWindow(wndObjList, xDiv1 + SBS, toolHeight, xDiv2 - xDiv1 - (SBS * 2), windowHeight - toolHeight - statusHeight, FALSE);

    if (!bDualMonitor)
    {
    MoveWindow(wndRender, xDiv2 + SBS, toolHeight, rect.right - xDiv2 - SBS, yDiv - toolHeight - SBS, FALSE);
    //SendMessage(toolRender, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);

    MoveWindow(wndAreaList, xDiv2 + SBS, yDiv + SBS, xDiv3 - xDiv2 - (SBS * 2), windowHeight - statusHeight - yDiv - SBS, FALSE);

    MoveWindow(wndAreaInfo, xDiv3 + SBS, yDiv + SBS, rect.right - xDiv3 - SBS, windowHeight - statusHeight - yDiv - SBS, FALSE);
    }
    else if (bDualMonitor)
    {
        MoveWindow(wndAreaList, xDiv2 + SBS, toolHeight, rect.right - xDiv2 - SBS, yDiv - toolHeight, FALSE);

        MoveWindow(wndAreaInfo, xDiv2 + SBS, yDiv + SBS, rect.right - xDiv2 - SBS, windowHeight - statusHeight - yDiv - SBS, FALSE);
    }

    if (forceresize)
        MoveWindow(hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, FALSE);

    InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);
    }
  break; //WM_SIZE
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing FALSE for the bRepaint parameter in most of the MoveWindow calls?  The InvalidateRect at the end only invalidates the current window, not its children.